# Why my input value does not appear PHP HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, function, input

So, i'm doing a school work where i have to make a calculator with max 10 inputs, there's a button where i can add more inputs, but for some reasons when i submit the values it does not work, it only shows the first 2 inputs that are estatic in the page.

[image: 1]

i think the problem is related to the names, but can't find it

here's what i'm doing right now:

```
<body>
<table id="table">
    
    
    <tr id="adicionarcells">
        <form id="form1" name="form1" action="romanos.php" method="post">
        <td></td>
            <td>
               
                <input type="text" id="valor1" name="valor1" pattern="(^(?=[MDCLXVI])M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$)" required>
                <select id="operador1" name="operador1">
                    <option value="value1" selected>+</option>
                    <option value="value2">-</option>
                    <option value="value3">*</option>
                    <option value="value4">/</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="valor2" name="valor2" pattern="(^(?=[MDCLXVI])M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$)" required>
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="adiciona" value="+" style="width: 20px;" onclick="myFunction();">
                <input type="submit" value="=" style="width: 20px;">
            </td>
        </form>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <!-- <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="valida();">Enviar</button> -->
<!-- <div id="mensagem" align="center"
    style="position:fixed; top:20px; left:10%; width:80%; padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; display:none;"></div> -->
```

```
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var rowCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    var row = document.getElementById("adicionarcells");
    var x = row.insertCell(-1);
    i++
    console.log(rowCount);
    x.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" id=\"valor" + rowCount + "\" name=\"valor" + rowCount + "\" pattern=\"(^(?=[MDCLXVI])M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$)\" required><select id=\"operador" + rowCount +"\" name=\"operador" + rowCount + "\"><option value =\"value1\" selected >+</option ><option value =\"value2\">-</option><option value =\"value3\">*</option><option value =\"value4\">/</option></select>";
    if (rowCount == 11) {
        document.getElementById("adiciona").disabled = true;
    }
}
```

obs: it does add the inputs, but the values does not appear in my php

Comment: Is the table inside the `<form>`?

Comment: BTW, if you use `'` as the string delimiter for `x.innerHTML`, you wouldn't need to escape all the `"` and it will be much easier to read and write.

Comment: Add the HTML of the table and form.

Comment: it is inside a form, i just edited it, thanks for the tip!!

Comment: The form is inside the table. The table needs to be inside the form. You have invalid HTML.

Comment: The children of `<tr>` have to be `<td>` or `<th>`, you can't wrap `<form>` around the cells.

Comment: @Barmar beat me to it. I would also suggest suggest using `fetch` or the `XMLHttpRequest` to send and receive data from the Server, instead of archaic form submission.

Comment: thank you so much!!!! i'm just starting to learn how to code in school so i'm a beginner yet, this really helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the form around the entire table, not the cells of the row.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" action="romanos.php" method="post">
  <table id="table">
    <tr id="adicionarcells">
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="valor1" name="valor1" pattern="(^(?=[MDCLXVI])M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$)" required>
        <select id="operador1" name="operador1">
          <option value="value1" selected>+</option>
          <option value="value2">-</option>
          <option value="value3">*</option>
          <option value="value4">/</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="valor2" name="valor2" pattern="(^(?=[MDCLXVI])M*(C[MD]|D?C{0,3})(X[CL]|L?X{0,3})(I[XV]|V?I{0,3})$)" required>
      </td>
      <td></td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" id="adiciona" value="+" style="width: 20px;" onclick="myFunction();">
        <input type="submit" value="=" style="width: 20px;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```